# Find the edges of a numpy array that 95% data within them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, percentage

I have a numpy array with tens of thousand elements. I want to find the critical elements, within which 95% of the data falls. For example,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.linspace(1,200,200)
```

then the two elements within which 95% data fall are 5 and 195. The numpy function `percentile` only returns one value, which is not what I want. Any one knows any module to do that?

Comment: Of course percentile can do that: you just need the 2.5% and the 97.5% percentiles.

Comment: Note that your actual question does not have a unique answer: 1 and 191 are also correct, (and 2, 192, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return both values at once.  In fact, the second argument can be a list with as many percentiles as you'd like to calculate.

```
np.percentile(a, [2.5, 97.5])
```

Then to capture all the data within the desired range do this:

```
lower, upper = np.percentile(a, [2.5, 97.5])
a[(a > lower) & (a < upper)]
```